# Set tab indicator height to match parent/tab height

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tablayout

Is there any way I can set the height of the tab indicator to the tab's height in android?

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_mode_tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/mode_indicator"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="30dp"
        />
```

I am able to do it by hardcoding the layout_height and tabIndicatorHeight to 30dp. But is it any better way to do it? Using wrap_content or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but you can use

```
app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
```